# iPhone - Entire Laptop Hard Drive Been Formatted, but iPhone Still contains Music & Pictures...What To Do?

Tags: iphone, format

My entire Laptop hard drive has been formatted however my iPhone still contains all the data I had synced to it via iTunes. Is there a way I can resync my iPhone with a new install of iTunes without having to format and lose all of my iTunes data?!?!

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Gosh, so careless! If you can find access to a Mac, use this software - [PhoneView](http://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/).

I have used it once, it works pretty well. Good luck! Sincerely hope you can salvage as much as possible!

Comment: I have used that also +1

Comment: This isn't the forum for "Me too!" but I've also used it with some success and I would recommend it +1

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows there are several tools for recovering music from your iPhone, they were covered in this answer:

[How can I transfer music from my iPhone to my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/25446/transfer-music-from-iphone-to-the-computer/)

Once you get iTunes reinstalled, before you do anything else, turn off all syncing. Then use iTunes to backup the phone.

Once you know you have the phone backed up, then you can setup your sync for contacts etc and let iTunes sync the data from your phone back to iTunes and the apps you have chosen to sync the data to.

When you reinstall your computer you need to make sure you tell iTunes not to manage your music automatically until you have copied the music back into the iTunes library. Otherwise if you aren't careful iTunes will delete all the music on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

If your music was legally acquired via iTunes it will automatically prompt you to transfer that music back to your computer.

Photos should also be no problem to sync back to your computer no matter how you acquired them, just open iPhoto.