# Losing music on my iPhone

Tags: iphone

I had a virus on my computer and had to restore it. Now when I connect to iTunes (after re-installing iTunes) a prompt appears asking me to delete the songs from my iphone before the sync process can complete. I don't want to lose any of my songs on my iphone. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/25446/transfer-music-from-iphone-to-the-computer/).  Its answers list a large number of utilities that can be used to transfer the music from your iPhone back to your computer.

Comment: the implication here being to re-add the iphone's current files to the itunes library so itunes will stop trying to delete the iphone's current files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can disable this "feature" of iTunes by **unchecking** the ***"automatically sync music & media"*** option under iTunes' device settings for that particular iPhone.  This places media management under a more manual control, but it should prevent iTunes from trying to delete the files on your device.

Disclaimer: I've only assisted my relatives with iPod/iTunes stuff, I don't use them myself.