# Transfer music from iPhone to PC?

Tags: iphone, music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transferring Music from iPod to iTunes?](https://superuser.com/questions/15420/transferring-music-from-ipod-to-itunes)

I have recently lost my hard drive with all my music on it, but still have music on my iPhone.

I would like to know how to transfer the iPhone music back onto my PC.

Any ideas would be helpful...

Comment: Check out the question I edited into your post - it deals with how to transfer music from an iPod to iTunes, should be a very similar process...

Comment: Another dupe would be [Transfer music from iPhone to computer](http://superuser.com/questions/25446/transfer-music-from-iphone-to-the-computer)

Comment: @studiohack Please **DO NOT** insert duplicate links into questions. It creates work for moderators when closing questions. The system will do it automatically when closed. Continuing to do so will be considered abuse.

Comment: @Diago: I did not realize that at all, my sincere apologies.  I will refrain from doing that in the future, and instead post the possible dupe link as a comment.  again, I apologize, I didn't know.